# How can higher order function in Kotlin use another parameter as parameter of function type parameter

Tags: android, kotlin, syntax, parameters, higher-order-functions

Learning Functional Programming in Kotlin, I've run into some problems in understanding

```
fun exampleFunction(name : String, paramFun : (String) -> Unit){
  ...some body code...
}
```

When I declare such function, as seen above, function is taking 2 parameters - String type 'name' and function type 'paramFun'.

how can paramFun, which is a function and passed as an input for exampleFunction, use name (which is parameter for exampleleFunction) as its parameter

like

```
fun exampleFunction(name : String, paramFun : (String) -> Unit){
  paramFun(name)
}
```

Comment: I probably don't understand your case fully, but it seems to me that you already answered your question. If you need to make the variable inside `exampleFunction()` accessible to `paramFun()` then just pass it as a parameter - exactly as you did in your second example.

Comment: Is your problem about the call site of the higher order function? Like how you pass the parameter lambda to the higher-order function?

Answer (score 0):

When you call a function in a function or whatever, try to remember that the fcuntion you call (paramFun(name)), is just a copy of that same function inside exempleFunction.

So basically, when you call exampleFunction, you have 2 variable you can use inside this function, after that, when you call paramFun(name), you can use name inside as you want.

When you call a function with parameter, you can use theses parameter as many time as you want in any order you want.

Ex : This is the same thing as this.

```
fun functionOne(a: Int, b: Int) {
    a = b //or// b = a
}
```

the function paramFun is the same parameter as a or b , but it's a function

Comment: fun main(){
    exampleFunction("Philip", {x: String -> println("hello $x")})
    
}

fun exampleFunction(name : String, paramFun : (String) -> Unit){
  paramFun(name)
}
`
if I have this code, why does it return hello Philip? why does x take "Philip" as argument?

Comment: You are making a function that is immediately being called, with name as a parameter.
" {x: String -> println("hello $x")} " is a function without any name and parameter.

Comment: @ceeoh94 I'm not sure which part is confusing to you. There is really no higher-order magic here. Your example is similar to case where a function just invokes another one, like this: https://gist.github.com/broo2s/ee689d14bd1857ec90b625e9caffd268

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understood your problem, because you already accomplished what you seem to have trouble with:

```kotlin
fun exampleFunction(name : String, paramFun : (String) -> Unit){
  paramFun(name)
}
```

If your problem is at the call site, here is how you would call `exampleFunction`:

```kotlin
exampleFunction(name = "the name param") { someParam -> 
    // do what you want with someParam here
}
```

With this call, `someParam` in the lambda would get the value provided as `name` parameter to `exampleFunction`, because the body of `exampleFunction` actually passes `name` as argument to the lambda when doing `paramFun(name)` (just like a regular function call).